# Как в Python достать число из массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, числа

Есть цикл который возвращает данные, нужно взять только второе значение (8 цифр). Подскажите куда бежать, хотя бы...

- [5453]
- [12345678]
- [ ]
- [124]

Мой код:

```
for r in result:
     res = r.get_text()
     res = [int(''.join(i)) for is_digit, i in groupby(res,str.isdigit) if is_digit]
     print (res)
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Почему значения в таких скобках, как list? Уточните, что значит  - "возвращает значения".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val = """5453
12345678

124"""

[ int(i) for i in val.split('\n') if i and int(i)>9999999]
[12345678]
```

Comment: вместо `i!=''` просто `i` -> `if i and int(i) > 9999999`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, согласен.

Comment: Лучше использовать  val.splitlines() вместо val.split('\n')